# Angularjs:radio button is not aligning in one line using the ng-repeat,tr,td

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have written simple angularjs code which will have the multiple radio buttons.I have implemented it using the ng-repeat,tr,td.
Below is the code,

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
   <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="subscription in entities">
            <td>
               <input type="radio" ng-model="subscription.checked" ng-value="true" ng-click="updateSelection($index, entities)" />{{subscription.name}}
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
   <script>
      var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
          $scope.entities = [{
                  name: 'Last Week',
                  id: 1,
                  checked: false
              }, {
                  name: 'Last Month',
                  id: 2,
                  checked: false
              }, {
                  name: 'Last year',
                  id: 3,
                  checked: false
              },
              {
                  name: 'Last 3 months',
                  id: 4,
                  checked: false
              },
              {
                  name: 'Last 6 months',
                  id: 5,
                  checked: false
              },
              {
                  name: 'Last 9 months',
                  id: 6,
                  checked: false
              }
          ]
          $scope.updateSelection = function(position, entities) {
              angular.forEach(entities, function(subscription, index) {
                  if (position != index)
                      subscription.checked = false;
                  else {
                      console.log(subscription.id);
                      $window.location.href = "/view_report/?q=" + subscription.id;
                  }
              });
          };

      });
   </script>
```

The code should display the all the buttons in to the single horizontal line because td is inside tr.However all the buttons are displayed in new row/line.
Please help.

Comment: can you provide the plunker link ?

Comment: How to create it?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/tiLFg8r8Xk8aR65aNcG9?p=preview

Comment: I have created:https://plnkr.co/edit/fj2xNOXueeFvpUkFLpuV?p=info

Comment: i had also created for your code. please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your ng-repeat to TD tag. Since you have in TR tag, it will keep repeating the TR also.

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
   <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="subscription in entities">
               <input type="radio" ng-model="subscription.checked" ng-value="true" ng-click="updateSelection($index, entities)" />{{subscription.name}}
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
   <script>
      var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
          $scope.entities = [{
                  name: 'Last Week',
                  id: 1,
                  checked: false
              }, {
                  name: 'Last Month',
                  id: 2,
                  checked: false
              }, {
                  name: 'Last year',
                  id: 3,
                  checked: false
              },
              {
                  name: 'Last 3 months',
                  id: 4,
                  checked: false
              },
              {
                  name: 'Last 6 months',
                  id: 5,
                  checked: false
              },
              {
                  name: 'Last 9 months',
                  id: 6,
                  checked: false
              }
          ]
          $scope.updateSelection = function(position, entities) {
              angular.forEach(entities, function(subscription, index) {
                  if (position != index)
                      subscription.checked = false;
                  else {
                      console.log(subscription.id);
                      $window.location.href = "/view_report/?q=" + subscription.id;
                  }
              });
          };

      });
   </script>
```

Also, find the plunker link for your code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tiLFg8r8Xk8aR65aNcG9?p=preview

Comment: Hi, Please read my answer first line.  "Just move your ng-repeat to TD tag... since you have in TR tag it will keep repeating the TR also". You had ng-repeat in your TR tag..instead it should be assigned to TD tag since you just want to repeat the TD tags, not rows (TRs).